# VS Code - How to control arbitrary settings via keystrokes

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, keystroke

VS Code has several features that I find useful sometimes, and distracting other times. I know how to change them, but it is too cumbersome to do that in real-time as my context & needs change. Is there a way to create keystrokes that will toggle specific settings, or set them a particular way, if there isn't already a command for that behavior?

The settings I'd like to be able to quickly enable/disable w/out resorting to the settings editor are:

- Hover (tool-tips) on functions, params, and variables in the editor
- Suggestions while typing in the editor
- in-line hints in the editor

I've done several searches already. If there's a magic phrase I didn't think of to use & this question is already answered, please point me in the right direction!

Side note: I do see that I can disable Editor -> Hover, and then hover over something, and hit cmd-opt-shift-space, and see the tooltip. That is not what I'm looking for, I'm looking for a way to change the hover (and other) settings themselves via keystrokes.

Thanks,
Avram